# Add language to URI based on cookie with htaccess & set cookie based on uri

Tags: .htaccess, cookies

I have a multilanguage site that uses cookies to store language information. I need to write a .htaccess script that

a) checks if a language cookie is set, and if the URI doesn't contain it. If it doesn't, then add it to the URI.

Right now I have this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} language=([a-z]{2}) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^%1/(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/%2 [L,NC,R=302]
```

While this gives me the proper URI, ("domain.com/en/") it gives me an error saying the page isn't redirecting properly.

b) checks if a language parameter is set in the URI, and if sets the appropriate cookie.

The code I've got so far for this is:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})(.*)/$ - [co=language:$1:.domain.com:7200:/]
```

But this only sets the cookie after you leave the page. So I would have to add '/fr/' to the address, then refresh *twice*

I've tried looking all over Google and Stack Overflow but I can't seem to get this working!

Answer (score 0):

request uri always starts with a `/`.
Also %1 only applies to the last RewriteCond, so I think your code should be

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} language=([a-z]{2}) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(%1)/(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/%2 [L,NC,R=302]
```

The cookie being set after leaving the page seems strange. The cookie is set in the responce, so it will only appear in the request-headers at the next request. Don't know if this is what you mean, but this is the normal behavior. Try checking `document.cookie` in javascipt

**edit:** Above code will not work. see below for my updated version. I added your cookie setting rule above and added the `L` flag so the rules beneath it won't get executed if it matches, therefore preventing a infinite loop of redirects, which is what firefox means with "not redirecting properly".

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})(/.*)?$ - [co=language:$1:.domain.com:7200:/]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})(/.*)?$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} language=([a-z]{2}) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: I'm new to .htaccess - I didn't know the %1 only applies to the last RewriteCond, thanks! I tried what you suggested, but it didn't work. It's appending the language but Firefox is saying that the page isn't redirecting properly.

Comment: I tried your new suggestions and it still gives me an infinite loop and the uri becomes http://domain.com/fr/fr/fr/fr/fr/fr/fr/fr/fr/fr/fr/fr/fr/fr/fr/fr/fr/fr/fr/fr/

Comment: This redirected to domain.com/fr/404.shtml if I have the cookie; and if I don't have the cookie and go to domain.com/fr/ then it only sets it when I view the page the second time

Comment: Please show me the rest of your htaccess, because a redirect to 404.shtml should not occur normally.

Comment: I've decided to stop trying to do this with .htaccess/cookies and instead I'm going to handle it purely with PHP. Thanks for the help though!